# External Configuration of Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building out a small Node app using Express.js and, in an effort to keep my `server.js` file as clean as possible, I'd like to build my configuration in an external file. Here's how the server looks:

```
// server.js
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();
app.enable( 'trust proxy' );

// Set application config params
require( './config.js' )( app, express );

// Load routes and start listening...
require( './routes' )( app );
app.listen( app.get( 'port' ) );
```

My `config.js` file sets a few defaults and then updates or overrides the config in `NODE_ENV`-specific configuration functions.  Everything would be fine except for that pesky timing.

My routes need access to some of the configuration values. Is there a way to ensure that my routes are loaded and my server starts only starts listening only *after* the configuration is completely loaded?  Is there a better way?

I get the event loop, but I am brand-spanking new to node/express so I'm open to pretty much anything. I'm kind of making this up as I go along by cobbling together what I know I'd like to do based on experience with what I read about in various articles or documentation sources. I don't think I'm too off base here, but maybe that's being overly optimistic.

**UPDATE**

My `config.js`.

```
module.exports = function( app, express ) {
  var config = this;

  app.configure( function() {
    app.set( 'port', 3000 );
    app.set( 'datasources',   {
      'api'   : {...},
      'mysql' : {...}
    });
    app.use( express.logger() );
    app.use( express.bodyParser() );
    app.use( express.cookieParser() );
    app.use( express.methodOverride() );
    app.use( app.router );
  });

  // dev-specific config
  app.configure( 'development', function() {
    console.log( 'Loading development configuration' );

    app.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }) );

    // update the mysql config with a connection object
    var datasources = app.get( 'datasources' );
    var mysqlConnection = require( 'mysql' ).createConnection({...});
    datasources.mysql.connection = mysqlConnection;

    app.set( 'datasources', datasources );
  });

  // stg-specific config
  app.configure( 'staging', function() {
    console.log( 'Loading staging configuration' );

    app.use( express.errorHandler() );

    // update the mysql config with a connection object
    var datasources = app.get( 'datasources' );
    var mysqlConnection = require( 'mysql' ).createConnection({...});
    datasources.mysql.connection = mysqlConnection;

    app.set( 'datasources', datasources );
  });


  // prd-specific config
  app.configure( 'production', function() {
    console.log( 'Loading production configuration' );
    app.use( express.errorHandler() );
  });


  console.log( app.get( 'datasources' ) );
  console.log( 'Configuration loaded' );

  return config;
};
```

Comment: Here's how I do it. Allows you to override config values based one  environment http://www.chovy.com/node-js/managing-config-variables-inside-a-node-js-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code inside your config is all synchronous this should work:

```
// server.js
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();
var config = require( './config.js' );  // load config
app.enable( 'trust proxy' );

// -----------------------------------------------
// If the code inside your config is all synchronous this call 
// will block, which is what you want.
config(app, express );

// Load routes and start listening...
require( './routes' )( app );
app.listen( app.get( 'port' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hector. I've updated my question with my config content. Making the change you suggested didn't have any real impact. Does the `config.js` content help clarify my issue in any way?

Comment: Nothing in your config strikes me as odd. Does it work as expected if you include that code as part of your app.js rather than as an external file?

Comment: So...that was weird. I had a typo in my first route that had been there all along, but only now started complaining about. I don't know what I did differently, but fix the typo and stuff just worked. Imagine that. Thanks a lot for your help, Hector.

Answer (score 2):

Assign callback to your config.js module, let make it look like

```
require( './config.js' )( app, express, finish );
var finish = function(){
    // Load routes and start listening...
   require( './routes' )( app );
   app.listen( app.get( 'port' ) );
}
```

And in your config method, use a module like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) and make all your loadings sync at the end and callback the function. Example:

```
**config.js**
module.exports = function(app,express,finish){
    function loadConfig1(cb){
        fs.readFile("....", function(){ // Or someother else async function
              ...  if succesfull, cb(null);
              ...  if fail, cb("error!!!!");
         });
    }
    ....
    function complete(err, results){
         if (!err){
            finish(); // you guarantee that all the functions are completed succesfully
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mustafa. Your config example and mine don't quite line up so it's hard for me to identify key aspects. I'd rather not introduce another library if I can avoid it. Ultimately, my goal is to make my gateway file as clean & legible as possible.

Comment: If it is async, I am afraid there is no other way

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently working on an extension to Express which allows pure json external routing configuration.  I plan to open source this project in the near future.  If anyone is interested I'd be happy to share an early preview of this project via Github and NPM

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * settings
   */
  config:{
    "controller_directory" : "routes"
  },

  /**
   * defaults to ./routes directory
   */
  filters: {
    secure: "secure.securityListener",
    global:"secure.globalListener"
  },
  /**
   * defaults to ./routes directory
   * order matters for filters
   * filters should always contain a path which calls next();
   * router should be the final destination to a request
   *
   * possible verbs are [use, all, get, post, delete ...]
   * "use" is the default, "mount" path is stripped and is not visible to the middleware function.
   * other verbs will not strip out the "mount" path
   */
  routes: {
    global: {"filters": ["global"]},
    index:{path:"/", "controller": "index"},
    users:{path:"/users", "controller": "users", "filters": ["secure"]},
    prices:{path:"/prices", "controller": "prices"},
    software:{path:"/software", "controller": "software"},
    auth:{path:"/auth", "controller": "secure.onAuthentication", "verb": "get"}
  }

};
```